# ESLint Unresolved Module

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I am currently working with the [vss-web-extension-sdk](https://github.com/microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk). I am using ESLint, [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import), and [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript) to validate the files.

```
import { WidgetSettings, WidgetStatus } from "TFS/Dashboards/WidgetContracts";
```

The line above, extracted from my `run.ts`, throws the following error.

> Unable to resolve path to module 'TFS/Dashboards/WidgetContracts'. eslint(import/no-unresolved).

However, when I control-click on the import in VSCode, it navigates to the module in `tfs.d.ts`. I am doing something incorrectly to make the resolver not detect the module?

---

My `tsconfig.json` has

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "types": [
            "vss-web-extension-sdk"
        ]
    }
}
```

and my `.eslintrc.json` has

```
{
  "settings": {
    "plugins": [
      "import"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "import/no-unresolved": "error"
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {}
    }
  }
}
```

---

*Install Commands*

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-import typescript-eslint-parser eslint-import-resolver-typescript
npm install --save vss-web-extension-sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your baseUrl and your rootDir in your tsconfig.json to specify where that absolute path starts.

See here: https://maxisam.github.io/2017/01/03/rootDirs-in-tsconfig/